# Remove CGI from IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

I ran some security scan and the scan said that all kind of CGI stuff are potential thread.
This is part of the result :

> (ash) is present in the cgi-bin directory
>
> (bash) is present in the cgi-bin directory
>
> By exploiting this vulnerability, a malicious user may be able to
>   execute arbitrary commands on a remote system. In some cases, the
>   hacker may be able to gain root level access to the system, in which
>   case the hacker might be able to cause copious damage to the system,
>   or use the system as a jumping off point to target other systems on
>   the network for intrusion and/or denial of service attacks.

and many more related to cgi-bin directory. First I searched all the server for cgi-bin folder and it did not find any. Second I'm running my website on pure .NET and I don't use any scripts like php. Question is how can I remove this CGI thing from the IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGI is a sub role of IIS.

In server 2012 Go to remove roles and drill down the following tree

```
[X] Web Server (IIS)                                    
[X] Web Server                                                 
    [X] Application Development                     
        [X] .NET Extensibility 3.5                  
        [X] .NET Extensibility 4.5                  
        [X] Application Initialization              
        [X] ASP                                     
        [X] ASP.NET 3.5                             
        [X] ASP.NET 4.5                             
        [ ] CGI   <==== Make sure it is not checked!                                  
        [X] ISAPI Extensions                        
        [X] ISAPI Filters                           
        [X] Server Side Includes                    
        [ ] WebSocket Protocol
```

This insures that it is disabled and will not cause any security risks.